# HerePositioningClient fails to initalize

Tags: flutter, here-api

While working with HERE-SDK for flutter, HerePositioningClient fails to initialize with the error:

```
onInitializationFailed. API token that failed: com.here.services.location.LocationServices$1@2bdef2b
```

Additionally, the ActivityThread throws this error:

```
E/ActivityThread(12002): Service com.here.services.internal.LocationService has leaked IntentReceiver com.here.odnp.util.AlarmTimer$Scheduler@163882d that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()? 
E/ActivityThread(12002): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.here.services.internal.LocationService has leaked IntentReceiver com.here.odnp.util.AlarmTimer$Scheduler@163882d that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

**Update:**

Fixed this issue by adding all the possible permissions required as in the example files provided. Just adding Location and Activity permission was not enough.

Comment: Hello,
Would it be possible to provide more info on what kind of use case and environment(are you using example application or something?) you had when you saw this symptom?

It would be great if you could provide me specific version information as well.